# Celery MongoClient Opened Before Fork

Tags: mongodb, celery, pymongo

I am getting the following error running celery==4.4.5 and pymongo=3.10.1 with MongoDB 3.4 as a replica set. The worker has a concurrency of 16. I see this error. Sometimes its benign but sometimes it is causing deadlock for the child workers.

```
[2020-09-01 22:39:07,065: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-18164] /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:154: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with connect=False, or create client after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#pymongo-fork-safe>
```

I'm using the default MongoDB backend found here: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.4.5/celery/backends/mongodb.py

The part that I believe I am having a problem with is _get_connection.

```
def _get_connection(self):
        """Connect to the MongoDB server."""
        if self._connection is None:
            from pymongo import MongoClient

            host = self.mongo_host
            if not host:
                # The first pymongo.Connection() argument (host) can be
                # a list of ['host:port'] elements or a mongodb connection
                # URI.  If this is the case, don't use self.port
                # but let pymongo get the port(s) from the URI instead.
                # This enables the use of replica sets and sharding.
                # See pymongo.Connection() for more info.
                host = self.host
                if isinstance(host, string_t) \
                   and not host.startswith('mongodb://'):
                    host = 'mongodb://{0}:{1}'.format(host, self.port)
            # don't change self.options
            conf = dict(self.options)
            conf['host'] = host
            if self.user:
                conf['username'] = self.user
            if self.password:
                conf['password'] = self.password

            self._connection = MongoClient(**conf)

        return self._connection
```

I did try a suggestion mentioned here about sending connect=False to the mongoclient. It did not fix the problem for me though. https://github.com/mitmedialab/DataBasic/issues/29

I understand pymongo is not fork safe. I don't understand how to make the Celery backend fork safe when working with MongoDB. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Are you doing anything in your application before celery forks?

Comment: I set an environment variable that holds the name I want for my eventual log file. Nothing with the database